# Prevent Pandas from Stripping Symbol Characters

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas seems to be stripping leading characters from records in a table, and I'm not sure why. Each record is 5 numbers, and some are preceded by a symbol (`-`, `+`, `~`). ex: `~12345`, `+67890`, `-99999`.

Using the code below, I read the data from a .xls into a dataframe, drop a field, rename a field, rename the sheet, and rearrange the columns. Last, it is saved as a .xlsx.

The end product looks good, aside from the fact that the records in `CDP_PLACEFP` have the symbols stripped. I.e., the values above become `123456`, `67890`, `-99999` (for some reason the minus is not removed like the others).

The initial table contains the correct values. Is there an explicit command I need to give to prevent this?

```
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(cheapet_cdp_changes, cheapet_table_initial)
df = pd.read_excel(cheapet_table_initial)
df = df.drop(['FID'], axis=1) #Drop FID column
df = df.rename(columns={"TEMP_FP":"CDP_PLACEFP"}) #Rename TEMP_FP to CDP_PLACEFP
df = df.reindex(columns = ['PRIM_ID', 'STATEFP', 'COUNTYFP', 'CDP_PLACEFP']) #Rearrange columns
df.to_excel(os.path.join(pf, 'CHEAPET_{}.xlsx'.format(stcou)), sheet_name = 'CHEAPET', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `converters` parameter in `read_excel()` to read as a string.

```
df = pd.read_excel(cheapet_table_initial, converters={'your_column_name':str, ...)
```

Reference [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)